# As a client how do I request an access token from the Identity Server using client ID & secret then use the token to gain access to the API?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, webhooks

Hello new to stack overflow and programming.

I have a simple ASP.NET Core web app and am using ngrok to host my app, and I want to be able to call to a company's identity server so that I have an access token to be able to access their API and create Webhooks to receive notifications for different events.

I already have a

- clientID
- Secret
- URL (given by ngrok)

for the request body to receive the response.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Microsoft authentication libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) to achieve this.which is very easy to implement.

MSAL Library is just an implementation for enabling developers to acquire tokens from the Microsoft identity platform endpoint.

Since you already have  ClientID, Secret and Redirect URL you can get a token as [Acquire a token and call Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop).

However, I think what you really want is to integrate AAD. You can easily [enable AAD authentication for your .NET web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp).  It uses `OWIN` middleware.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. As I am the client developer I want to connect to a third party API and to do this I need to first get a token from their Identity server and then I am able to use there API. 
I have looked at your links and am confused in how I can use them. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi @Kayla555,For your scenario you can use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) which does not require user login.Ask them to register an app in Azure portel and give require permissions to use this flow